# What trophies unlock the bonus themes in Final Fantasy XIII?

Tags: ps3, final-fantasy-13

In the PS3 version of Final Fantasy XIII, there are a number of unlockable bonus themes.  After completing the main storyline, I only have three of the themes unlocked.  What trophies do I need to complete in order to unlock all the themes?

(Your answer may also explain how to unlock the themes on the Xbox 360, assuming the themes exist on that system.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [this page](http://cheats.ign.com/ob2/068/826/826843.html#64782) it lists them:

> Unlockable: Dashboard Themes
>
> Win the Trophies below to unlock
>   dashboard themes.
>
> - Fang - Get the "Treasure Hunter    (Gold)" Trophy / Held every weapon
>     and accessory.
> - Hope - Get the "Instrument of Change    (Gold)" Trophy / Witnessed
>     the       dawn of a new crystal
>     legend.
> - Lightning - Get the "Superstar    (Gold)" Trophy / Earned a 5-star
>     ranking in the battle to determine
>     the world's fate.
> - Sazh - Get the "Lore Master (Gold)"    Trophy / Discerned the full
>     attributes of 100 enemies.
> - Serah - Get the "Ultimate Hero    (Platinum)" Trophy / Acquired all
>     trophies.
> - Snow - Get the "L'Cie Paragon (Gold)"    Trophy / Earned a 5-star
>     ranking    for all Cie'th Stone
>     missions
> - Vanille - Get the "Instrument of    Faith (Silver)" Trophy / Defied
>     destiny's charge and embarked on a
>     different path.

Good luck with some of them. I've only gotten four so far. It'll take quite a bit of grinding for full crystarium/those T. things for the last weapons, and those latter Cie'th Stone Missions are hard! :O

Comment: Ugh.  I wanted Fang's theme, but I really don't have the time to grind the stuff necessary to upgrade all the items.  Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, Treasure Hunter is the most difficult and time consuming to obtain.

Comment: I believe it is actually Ultimate Hero. :p